# How can I update form with attachement image using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, multipartform-data, form-data

I use a form with 5 input type text as name nm ,gd,pn,al,np and input type file 'image' as name file.
I'm using this code but it didnt work, I don't know what is the problem!
any help please..
thank you in advance!

```
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="updatedata('<?php echo $row['cin']; ?>')" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>
  </div>

function updatedata(str){

    var id = str;
            var m_data = new FormData();    
            m_data.append( 'nm', $('input[name=nm]'+str).val());
            m_data.append( 'gd', $('input[name=gd]'+str).val());
            m_data.append( 'pn', $('input[name=pn]'+str).val());
            m_data.append( 'al', $('input[name=al]'+str).val());
            m_data.append( 'np', $('input[name=np]'+str).val());
            m_data.append( 'file', $('input[name=file]')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "updatedata.php?id="+id,
       data: m_data

    })
    }
```

Comment: didnt work?? Can you please elaborate it??

Comment: Is the function `updatedata` defined before the `onclick` handler is set?

Comment: @hjpotter91, sorry I didn't get you , can you explain me ?

Comment: I want to transfer updated text input , file name,file path of the image to an other page for making update query mysql